# How to determine the last business day in a given month?

Tags: .net

How can I calculate the last business day of the month in .NET?

Comment: I would think you need to define "business day".  M-F would be the obvious answer, but there's the question of holidays; is that in your definition?  And then there comes the question of what country, etc.

Comment: I don't believe there's a built in way, but it shouldn't be too hard to write a method to figure it out.

Comment: And working hours too... 6pm on a friday may not count...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would do it like this for a Monday through Friday business week:

```
var holidays = new List<DateTime>{/* list of observed holidays */};
DateTime lastBusinessDay = new DateTime();
var i = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
while (i > 0)
{
  var dtCurrent = new DateTime(year, month, i);
  if(dtCurrent.DayOfWeek < DayOfWeek.Saturday && dtCurrent.DayOfWeek > DayOfWeek.Sunday && 
   !holidays.Contains(dtCurrent))
    {
      lastBusinessDay = dtCurrent;
      i = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      i = i - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any good way to modify this to find Monday through Friday business weeks including holidays?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming business days are monday to friday (this doesn't account for holidays), this function should return the proper answer:

```
Function GetLastBusinessDay(ByVal Year As Integer, ByVal Month As Integer) As DateTime
    Dim LastOfMonth As DateTime
    Dim LastBusinessDay As DateTime

    LastOfMonth = New DateTime(Year, Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, Month))

    If LastOfMonth.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then 
        LastBusinessDay = LastOfMonth.AddDays(-2)
    ElseIf LastOfMonth.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
        LastBusinessDay = LastOfMonth.AddDays(-1)
    Else
        LastBusinessDay = LastOfMonth
    End If

    Return LastBusinessDay

End Function
```

Answer (score 9):

I could think of this simple C# code which gives you the last business day of current month. This only takes Saturday or Sunday as holidays. Country specific local holidays should be handled manually.

```
private DateTime GetLastBusinessDayOfCurrentMonth()
{
    var lastDayOfCurrentMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month,  DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month));

    if(lastDayOfCurrentMonth.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        lastDayOfCurrentMonth = lastDayOfCurrentMonth.AddDays(-2);
    else if(lastDayOfCurrentMonth.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        lastDayOfCurrentMonth = lastDayOfCurrentMonth.AddDays(-1);

    return lastDayOfCurrentMonth;
}
```

Comment: Don't construct a date by calling `DateTime.Now` repeatedly: it may give the wrong result if called just before midnight local time.

Answer (score 6):

First, get the last day of the month.  Then keep decrementing until you're either past the beginning of the month, or have hit a date that validates as a "business day".

Answer (score 5):

general purpose, pseudocode:

```
Day day = getLastDayOfMonth
int days = getDaysInMonth
for i = days to 0
  if day is weekday
    if day is not holiday
      return day
    end if
  end if
  day = prevDay
  days--
end for

throw exception because no business day was found in the month
```

Comment: If only there was such a thing as a month without any business days.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ:

```
   public static DateTime GetLastBussinessDayCurrentMonth(DateTime[] holidays)
   {
        DateTime todayDateTime = DateTime.Today;

        return
            Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(todayDateTime.Year, todayDateTime.Month))
                .Select(day => new DateTime(todayDateTime.Year, todayDateTime.Month, day))
                .Where(
                    dt =>
                    dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
                    && (holidays == null || !holidays.Any(h => h.Equals(dt))))
                .Max(d => d.Date);
   }
```

### Explaining

Creating a list of integers with all days available in month

```
      Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(todayDateTime.Year, todayDateTime.Month))
```

Filtering only days that do not fall on weekends and do not fall on holidays

```
            .Where(
                dt =>
                dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
                && (holidays == null || !holidays.Any(h => h.Equals(dt))))
```

Create new datetime with the filtered dates

```
            .Select(day => new DateTime(todayDateTime.Year, todayDateTime.Month, day))

            .Max(d => d.Date);
```

Comment: Some explanation will help!

Comment: Don't construct a date by calling DateTime.Now or DateTime.Date repeatedly: it may give the wrong result if called just before midnight local time.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an additional method that can be used to get the closest previous or current business day which can then be used to get the last business day of the month - this also takes into account if you are adjusting for weekend holidays:

```
public static DateTime LastBusinessDayInMonth(int year, int month, bool adjustForWeekend = true)
{
    var lastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    return PreviousOrCurrentBusinessDay(new DateTime(year, month, lastDay), adjustForWeekend);
}

public static DateTime PreviousOrCurrentBusinessDay(DateTime? beforeOrOnDate = null, bool adjustForWeekend = true)
{
    var fromDate = beforeOrOnDate ?? DateTime.Today;
    var year = fromDate.Year;
    var month = fromDate.Month;
    var day = fromDate.Day;
    var holidays = UsHolidays(fromDate.Year, true).ToList(); // defined below
    var dtCurrent = new DateTime(year, month, day);

    while (!(dtCurrent.DayOfWeek < DayOfWeek.Saturday && dtCurrent.DayOfWeek > DayOfWeek.Sunday && !holidays.Contains(dtCurrent)))
    {
        dtCurrent = dtCurrent.AddDays(-1);
    }
    return dtCurrent;
}
```

I also use the US holidays in my calculation which I get from the following code I developed from looking at this post: http://geekswithblogs.net/wpeck/archive/2011/12/27/us-holiday-list-in-c.aspx

The code can be seen here for that:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> UsHolidays(int year, bool adjustForWeekend)
{
    return new List<DateTime>()
    {
        NewYears(year, adjustForWeekend),
        MlkDay(year),
        PresidentsDay(year),
        GoodFriday(year),
        MemorialDay(year),
        IndependenceDay(year, adjustForWeekend),
        LaborDay(year),
        Thanksgiving(year),
        Christmas(year, adjustForWeekend),
    };
}

public static DateTime NewYears(int year, bool adjustForWeekend)
{
    //NEW YEARS 
    return adjustForWeekend ? AdjustForWeekendHoliday(new DateTime(year, 1, 1).Date) : new DateTime(year, 1, 1).Date;
}

public static DateTime MemorialDay(int year)
{
    //MEMORIAL DAY  -- last monday in May 
    var memorialDay = new DateTime(year, 5, 31);
    var dayOfWeek = memorialDay.DayOfWeek;
    while (dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        memorialDay = memorialDay.AddDays(-1);
        dayOfWeek = memorialDay.DayOfWeek;
    }
    return memorialDay.Date;
}

public static DateTime IndependenceDay(int year, bool adjustForWeekend)
{
    //INDEPENCENCE DAY 
    return adjustForWeekend ? AdjustForWeekendHoliday(new DateTime(year, 7, 4).Date) : new DateTime(year, 7, 4).Date;
}

public static DateTime LaborDay(int year)
{
    //LABOR DAY -- 1st Monday in September 
    var laborDay = new DateTime(year, 9, 1);
    var dayOfWeek = laborDay.DayOfWeek;
    while (dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        laborDay = laborDay.AddDays(1);
        dayOfWeek = laborDay.DayOfWeek;
    }
    return laborDay.Date;
}

public static DateTime Thanksgiving(int year)
{
    //THANKSGIVING DAY - 4th Thursday in November 
    var thanksgiving = (from day in Enumerable.Range(1, 30)
                        where new DateTime(year, 11, day).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday
                        select day).ElementAt(3);
    var thanksgivingDay = new DateTime(year, 11, thanksgiving);
    return thanksgivingDay.Date;
}

public static DateTime Christmas(int year, bool adjustForWeekend)
{
    return adjustForWeekend ? AdjustForWeekendHoliday(new DateTime(year, 12, 25).Date) : new DateTime(year, 12, 25).Date;
}

public static DateTime MlkDay(int year)
{
    //Martin Luther King Day -- third monday in January
    var MLKDay = new DateTime(year, 1, 21);
    var dayOfWeek = MLKDay.DayOfWeek;
    while (dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        MLKDay = MLKDay.AddDays(-1);
        dayOfWeek = MLKDay.DayOfWeek;
    }
    return MLKDay.Date;
}

public static DateTime PresidentsDay(int year)
{
    //President's Day -- third monday in February
    var presDay = new DateTime(year, 2, 21);
    var dayOfWeek = presDay.DayOfWeek;
    while (dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        presDay = presDay.AddDays(-1);
        dayOfWeek = presDay.DayOfWeek;
    }
    return presDay.Date;
}

public static DateTime EasterSunday(int year)
{
    var g = year % 19;
    var c = year / 100;
    var h = (c - c / 4 - (8 * c + 13) / 25 + 19 * g + 15) % 30;
    var i = h - h / 28 * (1 - h / 28 * (29 / (h + 1)) * ((21 - g) / 11));

    var day = i - ((year + year / 4 + i + 2 - c + c / 4) % 7) + 28;
    var month = 3;

    if (day > 31)
    {
        month++;
        day -= 31;
    }

    return new DateTime(year, month, day);
}

public static DateTime GoodFriday(int year)
{
    return EasterSunday(year).AddDays(-2);
}

public static DateTime AdjustForWeekendHoliday(DateTime holiday)
{
    if (holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        return holiday.AddDays(-1);
    }
    return holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? holiday.AddDays(1) : holiday;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetLastDay(ByVal month As Int32, ByVal year As Int32) As Date
        Dim D As New Date(year, month, Date.DaysInMonth(year, month))
        For i As Integer = 0 To Date.DaysInMonth(year, month)
            Select Case D.AddDays(-i).DayOfWeek
                Case DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday 'Not a weekday
                Case Else  'Is a weekday.  Flag as first weekday found
                    Return D.AddDays(-i)
                    'you can add other code here which could also do a check for holidays or ther stuff since you have a proper date value to look at in the loop
            End Select
        Next
End Function
```

Answer (score -4):

Here is how to find the last day of the month in C#:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year,
                                   today.Month,
                                   DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year,
                                   today.Month));
```

[Source](http://geekprogrammers.com/question/how-can-i-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-in-c/)

Comment: The question is "How to determine the last **business** day in a given month". This answer is wrong.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.