# How to check if the current day is the Nth or Nth from last business day of the month?

Tags: c#, .net

I realize that similar questions to this have been asked, but I feel this questions has different requirements.

I need to check whether the current day is the Nth or Nth from last business day of the month. If it is, I kick off another task, else I exit.

Something like :

```
void doTask()
{
    if (NthFirstOrNthLastBusinessDay())
    {  // do stuff  }
    else 
    {  // do nothing  }
}

bool NthFirstOrNthLastBusinessDay()
{}
```

So far, I think I could follow the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273048/how-to-determine-the-last-business-day-in-a-given-month) to get the last business day of the month (and similarly the first business day of the month), then apply a bunch of conditions to calculate the Nth business day from that date.

Is there a better way?

For example, if N is 4, my task should only run if today is the 4th business day of the month or the 4th from last business day of the month.

Essentially, I call this method everyday, it checks whether the current day satisfies this condition, and if so it runs the task, otherwise it doesn't.

So, my task should run on 28th July, 2014 and 6th August, 2014 and then 26th August, 2014 and so on.

EDIT : 
Here is some code I wrote in case N=4 :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the current day is the 4th business day or the 4th last business day of the month
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> True if current day satisfies condition, false otherwise </returns>
    private bool NthFirstOrNthLastBusinessDay()
    {
        return (IsFourthBusinessDay() || IsFourthFromLastBusinessDay());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if today is the fourth business day of the month
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> True if today satisfies condition, else false </returns>
    private bool IsFourthBusinessDay()
    {
        var dateToday = DateTime.Today;

        var firstDayOfThisMonth = new DateTime(dateToday.Year, dateToday.Month, 1);

        switch (firstDayOfThisMonth.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                firstDayOfThisMonth = firstDayOfThisMonth.AddDays(4);
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                firstDayOfThisMonth = firstDayOfThisMonth.AddDays(3);
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                firstDayOfThisMonth = firstDayOfThisMonth.AddDays(3);
                break;
            default:
                firstDayOfThisMonth = firstDayOfThisMonth.AddDays(5);
                break;
        }  // firstDayOfMonth now contains first business day of month

        return dateToday == firstDayOfThisMonth;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if today is the fourth from last business day of the month
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> True if today satisfies condition, else false </returns>
    private bool IsFourthFromLastBusinessDay()
    {
        var dateToday = DateTime.Today;

        var lastDayOfThisMonth = new DateTime(dateToday.Year, dateToday.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateToday.Year, dateToday.Month));

        switch (lastDayOfThisMonth.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                lastDayOfThisMonth = lastDayOfThisMonth.AddDays(-4);
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                lastDayOfThisMonth = lastDayOfThisMonth.AddDays(-3);
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                lastDayOfThisMonth = lastDayOfThisMonth.AddDays(-3);
                break;
            default:
                lastDayOfThisMonth = lastDayOfThisMonth.AddDays(-5);
                break;
        }  // firstDayOfMonth now contains first business day of month

        return dateToday == lastDayOfThisMonth;
    }
```

Now I need to tweak the values for general N. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by nth first or nth last...  To me, an example of that would read: "what is the 3rd 1st business day of the month?"  Which doesn't make sense

Comment: I think it means Nth or Nth from last...? Why not find all of the business days and put them in a `List`. Then `days[3]` for 3rd business day of the month.

Comment: @Tom Sorry for the confusion. Added use case. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @crashmstr, you're right. English is not my first language, sorry. Also, I feel there should be a better solution than yours, since I should just be able to check the current day rather than calculating all business days of the month every time I run the task. What do you think?

Comment: To check if a day is the Nth (or Nth from last) business day, you need to know how many business days came before (or after). Thus you still need to check other days, right?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the OP comments to my original answer, I decided to write another function as an exercise.

Here it is (again - not fully tested):

```
// Nth day should not be larger than 14 - I have tested it
bool Nth_BusinessDay(int NthDay, DateTime current)
{
    // check we have NthDay larger than ZERO
    if (NthDay < 1)
        return false;

    // make sure the taget date is just a date - no time component
    DateTime target = current.Date;

    // make sure the specialDay is not larger than the current days in the month
    if (DateTime.DaysInMonth(target.Year, target.Month) > NthDay)
        return false;

    // start at the beginning
    DateTime NthStart = new DateTime(target.Year, target.Month, 1);
    // check if start date falls on the weekend
    if (NthStart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        NthStart = NthStart.AddDays(2); // jump TWO days to Monday
    if (NthStart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        NthStart = NthStart.AddDays(1); // jump ONE day to Monday

    // now add our Nth day
    NthStart = NthStart.AddDays(NthDay - 1);

    // if we land on weekend after we adjusted for the Nth - push it by two days
    if (NthStart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || NthStart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        NthStart = NthStart.AddDays(2);

    // start at the end and minus the Nth day
    DateTime NthEnd = new DateTime(target.Year, target.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(target.Year, target.Month));
    // check if the end date falls on the weekend - the difference here is the adjustment
    if (NthEnd.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        NthEnd = NthEnd.AddDays(-1); // jump ONE day back to Friday
    if (NthEnd.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        NthEnd = NthEnd.AddDays(-2); // jump TWO days back to Friday

    // now subject our Nth day from the End
    NthEnd = NthEnd.AddDays((NthDay - 1) * -1);

    // again if we land on weekend - adjust by two days
    if (NthStart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || NthStart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        NthStart = NthStart.AddDays(2);


    // check if our target day is one of the Nth day
    if (NthStart == target || NthEnd == target)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

And to use the function above:

```
void doTaskNthDay()
{
    if (Nth_BusinessDay(5, DateTime.Now))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

*Below is my original answer left here for informational purposes.*

I took the following code from: [.NET Date Compare: Count the amount of working days since a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165887/net-date-compare-count-the-amount-of-working-days-since-a-date).
I haven't tested this code but you could try something like this:

```
int BuinessDayCount(DateTime targetDay)
{
    // check if the target day is a weekend
    if (targetDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        return -1;
    if (targetDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        return -2;

    // get the start of the month
    DateTime start = new DateTime(targetDay.Year, targetDay.Month, 1);

    // create a target without any time component
    DateTime end = targetDay.Date;

    int workingDays = 0;
    while (start <= targetDay)
    {
        if (start.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
         && start.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            workingDays++;
        }
        start = start.AddDays(1);
    }

    return workingDays;
}
```

Then in your code I would do the follow:

```
void doTask()
{
    int businessDay = BuinessDayCount(DateTime.Now);
    if (businessDay == 5 || businessDay == 25)
    {  
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I think it will read better.

Comment: This looks better than what I was going for. Thanks. I was validating both conditions separately.

Comment: Would suggest an edit - the 25th business day may not be the 5th from last business day of the month (for some months it may not even exist). Someone else suggested that the DateTime.DaysInMonth property would be useful here.

Comment: What happens if the first day of the current month is a Sunday (take N=4)? Then : DateTime NthStart = new DateTime(target.Year, target.Month, 1).AddDays(NthDay - 1) ... this gives us a Wednesday. Whereas the first business day of this month would have been a Monday, hence the correct NthStart should be the Thursday.
Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: You are correct.  I didn't take into account that the first and last day of the month could be a weekend.  I will make the adjustment.

Comment: Pretty good, but there are only 5 business days in a week.  If you are looking for the 11th business day of a month, there are 2 weekends in there, so its actually sometime around the 14th day of the month.  I'm not sure your logic handles that case properly.

Comment: The deeper I go down the rabbit hole...  I was trying to avoid a loop logic; I am guessing there is no way around it.  I will update my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
int numOfOccurredBusinessDays = 0; // this will include current business day
int businessDaysLeft = 0;
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var monthIterator = new DateTime(DateTime.Year, DateTime.Month, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < DateTime.DaysInMonth; ++i, monthIterator.AddDay(1))
{
    if (monthIterator <= currentDate &&
     !monthIterator.Date.ToString("D").Contains("Sat") &&
     !monthIterator.Date.ToString("D").Contains("Sun"))
          numOfOccurredBusinessDays++;
    else if (monthIterator > currentDate &&
     !monthIterator.Date.ToString("D").Contains("Sat") &&
     !monthIterator.Date.ToString("D").Contains("Sun"))
          businessDaysLeft++;
}
```

Comment: okayish, but get rid of the conversion to string and string comparisons. that's slow.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a new System.DateTime object. Initialize it with the current year and current month (which can be obtained from DateTime.Now). Set the day to 30 if it's September/April/June/November, or 31, 28, etc.
2. Now you have a DateTime object representing the last day of the month. You can use DateTime.DayOfWeek to check if the day is a Saturday or Sunday (or holiday).
3. You can use DateTime.AddDays(-N) to "wind back" the DateTime object by a single day, then check again if it's a Saturday or Sunday (or holiday).
4. Repeat for whatever Nth last day of the month check you need to make.

Comment: Who said anything about this question being homework? Regardless, if a question is well written and on-topic, there is no problem with homework questions.

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks for the feedback, but I had already reformatted before you commented. As for homework, it's just a reasonable guess. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework) for the meta discussion

Comment: There's a method of the `DateTime struct` that tells you how many days a particular month in a particular year has. You don't need to write that logic.  Holidays, on the other hand, would require a list of dates to test for inclusion.

Comment: @TonyVitabile Good call. I forgot about the `DateTime.DaysInMonth` property.

Comment: @cjcurrie, thanks for the hints. This is the approach I'm following now (can post my code here if you want). The reason I posted the question was to see if someone already knows an optimal way to do this, or if there are .NET functions I can use. (If I wanted code review I would have posted in codereview.stackexchange. FWIW, this is not homework)