# Get x'th last working day (which is not a holiday) in month

Tags: c#, datetime

How can i get for example 4th last working day (which is not a holiday) from a month ?
In August its 26.8.2015 day (Wednesday)
In September its 25.9.2015 day (Friday)

My actual code is following (i get an inspiration from [here](https://lostinthegc.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/get-the-business-days-in-a-month-using-c/))
but i have an recursion and also it has syntax error.

```
 static bool getLastXthWorkingDay(int x)
        {
            var weekends = new DayOfWeek[] { DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday };
            int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
            int year = DateTime.Now.Year;

            IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("cs-CZ", true);
            var holidays = new DateTime[] { 
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("1.1.{0}",year),culture), 
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("6.4.{0}",year),culture),
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("1.5.{0}",year),culture), 
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("8.5.{0}",year),culture), 
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("5.7.{0}",year),culture), 
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("6.7.{0}",year),culture), 
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("28.9.{0}",year),culture), 
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("28.10.{0}",year),culture), 
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("17.11.{0}",year),culture),
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("24.12.{0}",year),culture), 
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("25.12.{0}",year),culture), 
                Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("26.12.{0}",year),culture)
            };

            //Fetch the amount of days in your given month.
            int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

            //Here we create an enumerable from 1 to daysInMonth,
            //and ask whether the DateTime object we create belongs to a weekend day,
            //if it doesn't, add it to our IEnumerable<int> collection of days.
            IEnumerable<int> businessDaysInMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, daysInMonth)
                                                   .Where(d => !weekends.Contains(new DateTime(year, month, d).DayOfWeek));

            var lastXthWorkingDay = businessDaysInMonth.Skip(Math.Max(0, businessDaysInMonth.Count() - x));

            // This code has syntax error ") expected" but i dont see where ?
            //if holidays.Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", lastXthWorkingDay, month, year),culture))
            //{    
            //    getLastXthWorkingDay(x-1);
            //} 
            //else { return true; }

        }
```

any idea ?

Comment: What is the syntax error says exactly? Also with holidays, you mean weekends, right?

Comment: Instead of parsing strings, you should use the `new DateTime()` constructor.

Comment: The error is ')' expected on the line holidays.Contains condition

Comment: No by holidays I mean feast like Christmas etc..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the last business day in a given month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273048/how-to-determine-the-last-business-day-in-a-given-month)

Comment: I don't see any recursion here.

Comment: because weekends != holidays, recursion is commented and is triggered only if workingDay = holiday

Comment: Your commented out code calls `isTodayLastXthWorkingDay`, we don't know what that is, so unless it calls `getLastXthWorkingDay` there is no recursion.

Comment: Is there a way for your function to return `false` ?  from what I can see, it is either true or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think i got it. Thank you all

```
static int GetLastXthWorkingDay(int year, int month, int x)
        {
            var weekends = new DayOfWeek[] { DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday };

            var holidays = new DateTime[] { 
                new DateTime(year, 4, 6),
                new DateTime(year, 5, 1), 
                new DateTime(year, 5, 8), 
                new DateTime(year, 7, 5), 
                new DateTime(year, 7, 6), 
                new DateTime(year, 9, 28), 
                new DateTime(year, 10, 28), 
                new DateTime(year, 11, 17), 
                new DateTime(year, 12, 24), 
                new DateTime(year, 12, 25), 
                new DateTime(year, 12, 26), 
            };

            //Fetch the amount of days in your given month.
            int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

            //Here we create an enumerable from 1 to daysInMonth,
            //and ask whether the DateTime object we create belongs to a weekend day,
            //if it doesn't, add it to our IEnumerable<int> collection of days.
            IEnumerable<int> businessDaysInMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, daysInMonth)
                                                   .Where(d => !weekends.Contains(new DateTime(year, month, d).DayOfWeek));

            var lastXthWorkingDay = businessDaysInMonth.Skip(Math.Max(0, businessDaysInMonth.Count() - x));

                foreach (var day in lastXthWorkingDay)
                {
                    if ( holidays.Contains(new DateTime(year, month, day)) )
                    {
                        return GetLastXthWorkingDay(year, month, x + 1);
                        //return day-1;
                    }
                    else { return day; }
                }

                return 0;
        }
```